# Querying a one-to-many relationship such that all the children returned only belong to the parents returned in the query

Tags: sql, postgresql

For the sake of simplicity we'll say that I have two tables `parent` and `child`.

```
Parent
------
id
ranking
```

and

```
Child
-----
id
parent_id
```

Parent has an `id` and `rank`, and child has an `id` and the id of its parent `parent_id`.

I want to get the top 20 parents with the highest `rank`, AND, in the same query, get all their respective children.

I can't think of a way to do it other than to iterate over every single parent, and then for every parent search the child table for the parent id.

Comment: How are the children to be returned? Are you thinking of having a row for each child? Or all of the children concatenated into a big varchar?

Comment: Start by selecting the 20 parents with the highest ranks (BTW: `rank` is a keyword; try to avoid using it as a column name)

Comment: ... and do you want french fries with it, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it relatively simply by comparing the Parent ID from the Child table to a sub-query. It's not the tidiest, but it should work for you. Obviously this is based on the ranking being 1 for best, etc.

```
SELECT p.id, c.id
FROM Child c
JOIN Parent p ON c.parent_id = p.id
WHERE c.parent_id
IN (SELECT id
    FROM Parent
    WHERE rank <= 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as below .I am not very sure if `postgresql` supports `TOP` , but this should give you the idea .

```
select p.id as parent
  ,c.id as child
  ,c.rank
from child c inner join parent p
  on c.id = p.id
where p.id IN
(select top 20 p.parent_id
from child c inner join parent p
  on c.id = p.id
order by rank desc) a
;
```